# Error at server side while executing dss query

Tags: sql, postgresql, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2dss 3.1.0 and wso2esb 4.7.0.I wish to fire select from esb.I have write select query in dss and dbs for this is like :

```
 <query id="Capp_select_emercontactid" useConfig="default">
      <sql>select userid,mailid,phonenumber from muser where phonenumber = ? or mailid = ?</sql>
      <result element="Entries" rowName="Entry">
         <element column="userid" name="userid" xsdType="string"/>
         <element column="mailid" name="mailid" xsdType="string"/>
         <element column="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" xsdType="string"/>
      </result>
      <param name="phonenumber" ordinal="1" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="mailid" ordinal="2" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>

 <operation disableStreaming="true" name="Capp_select_emercontactid_op">
      <call-query href="Capp_select_emercontactid">
         <with-param name="phonenumber" query-param="phonenumber"/>
         <with-param name="mailid" query-param="mailid"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
```

It's working fine in dss.
Now i have write a payload in esb like :

```
               <payloadFactory>
                  <format>
                     <p:Capp_select_emercontactid_op xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                        <p:phonenumber>$1</p:phonenumber>
                        <p:mailid>$2</p:mailid>
                     </p:Capp_select_emercontactid_op>
                  </format>
                  <args>
                     <arg expression="get-property('phoneno1')" evaluator="xml"/>
                     <arg expression="get-property('mailid1')" evaluator="xml"/>
                  </args>
               </payloadFactory>
               <log level="full"/>
               <send>
                  <endpoint>
                     <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/Capp_MuserDataservice/" format="soap11"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
```

When i'm hiting this proxy it didn't give responce..Why so?Is it correct configuration?Please let me know

Answer (score 1):

I never had any luck using the send mediator with the DSS.  Could you consider using the CalloutMediator instead (it's a synchronous send/response call so you may need to use a respond mediator after if you're wanting an immediate response to your client).

It'd look something like:

```
    <callout xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" action="Capp_select_emercontactid_op">
       <source xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xpath="//p:Capp_select_emercontactid_op"/>
       <target xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xpath="//p:Capp_select_emercontactid_op"/>
    </callout>
```